# How to get Microsoft Trial VM Windows 11 to launch on VM Workstation

Tags: windows, vmware, operating-systems, vmware-workstation

How to get Microsoft Trial Windows 11 VM to launch on VM Workstation

Answer (score -2):

1 Download and unzip file

.mf (195Bytes) .ovf (8.2K) .vmdk (23GB)

2 double click on .ovf

This should bring up dialog box Import Virtual Machine Name for the new virtual machine: e.g. Win 11 Trial Storage Path for the new virtual machine: browse to WinDev2030Eval-disk1.vmdk

3 New dialog box VMWare workstation
Importing Win 11 Trial (progress bar takes 5+ mins to complete)

4 Now double click on the Win11 Trial.vmx file

5a If you have an AMD processor for you host machine you may get

"Virtualised AMD-V/RVI is not supported on this platform. Continue without virtualised AMD-V/RVI?" Yes/No

Select No
If no dialog box skip to step 6

5b Within VMWare workstation, select the tab for the VM
 e.g. Win 11 Trial Below Devices double click on Processors This brings up a dialog box. On the right are Processor specific settings.
Untick Virtualize Intel VT-x/EPT or AMD-V/RVI Click on OK, to save the change.

6 The VM should start normally.

Comment: This answer looks like it was copied and pasted from a website.  If it was you should quote and cite your source.

Comment: I copied it from my entry on StackOverflow where it was rejected

Comment: The question or the answer? We have the same expectations with regards to quality that SO has, does not change the fact, it looks like you copied it from an external source outside of the SE community. In other words it doesn’t appear to have been written by you.

Comment: It was written by me (question and answer)